# Examine a bunch of huge files

Tags: grep, file-search, ack

I have a folder with big files (few GB each). I would like to search a`PATTERN`through these files. I can do this with `grep` or `ack`:

```
$ grep -n 'PATTERN' /path/to/files/*.log
```

Now, I have a list with all lines including `PATTERN`. However, I need some area includes these lines to see context: few lines before `PATTERN` occurs and few lines after it occurs. I would prefer to list these line blocks with coordinates of each (file and line number). How it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With gnu grep

```
grep -B <number_lines> -A <number_lines> -n 'PATTERN' /path/to/files/*.log
```

e.g. to get the 6 lines above the line grep matched, and 4 lines after it:

```
grep -B 6 -A 4 -n 'PATTERN' /path/to/files/*.log
```

From `man grep`

> **Context Line Control**
>   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>   Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.
>   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>                 Print  NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.